# Storing Socket.io Object in a persisted DB or redis

Tags: node.js, sockets, nginx, redis, socket.io

Building a customer service Chat application. Hence need to keep track of customers logged in sockets and attach them to Admin/agent room.

As of now, I have achieved this by using simple `JSON` object. But to scale app, I need to find out a place where I can store them. Since Socket object is in form of Circular JSON, I am not able to store it in Redis. I tried using 'Douglas Crockford's Cycle.js, but looks like it is changing the nature of the object in decycle / retrocycle.

Please help me finding a solution to keep track of customer & Agents sockets and connect them as a request comes in from agent's front end.

Current Solution:

```
// Admin Socket -

admins[socket.username] = socket;

// Customer socket

users[socket.roomID] = socket;
```

Need to run this solution on multi-core Linux machine using 16 cores for 16 Socket servers/node.js cluster proxied by Nginx. So need to quickly find a solution for robust architecture.

One more info:

1. I am using Redis for Sub/pub for scaling out.
2. And using Redis to store messages for short history.

P.S. (MongoDB is no more permitted in my org. Mongo Based solution will not work for me.)

Comment: Can you tell me why MongoDB is no more permitted in your org ?

Answer (score 2):

In order to scale to multiple nodes using Redis, please take a look at [socket.io-redis](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis)

By running socket.io with the socket.io-redis adapter you can run multiple socket.io instances in different processes or servers that can all broadcast and emit events to and from each other.

And also take a look at original thread on GitHub: [How can i store Socket object in Database](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/2697)

Comment: Can you please tell me the reason why you down voted?

Comment: Socket is not only about socket.io, https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket

Answer (score 1):

Sockets are not serializable, you cannot export them outside of your system (redis or any other external storage). This is because a socket represents a live network connection between your server and a client, it does't have meaning outside of the server, because there is no connection to represent.

What you probably need is to store active user sessions with all necessary information to recreate a connection and restore the session to its previous state: things like username, roomName etc.